# TYPO3 Database Queries

Tags: database, typo3, repository

I have a problem in my extension that I work with.
I got this error:

```
"TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.ContentObject.Exception.ProductionExceptionHandler": Oops, an error occurred! Code: 202008171404455cdd4e46 - {"exception":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Exception\\InvalidNumberOfConstraintsException: There must be at least one constraint or a non-empty array of constraints given.
```

and at the same time, I have this code in my repository

```php
$query->matching($query->logicalAnd($contraints));
```

my question is: how can I write the code in TYPO3 which matches with the condition:

> "at least one constraint or a non-empty array of constraints given".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, disable ExceptionHandler in ROOT TS:

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

As your eyception said: it seems you have had an empty array $contraints == [].
Please publish the hole code for detailed help!

Example:

```php
public function findUser(
    \VENDOR\Ext1\Domain\Model\MyModel $m
)
{
    $query = $this->createQuery();

    $constraints = [];
    $constraints[] = $query->equals('pid', $m->getPid());
    $constraints[] = $query->contains('type', $m->getType());

    if ($condition) {
        $constraints[] = $query->contains('topics', $m->getTopic());
    }

    $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd($constraints)
    );

    return $query->execute();

}
```